# BEA-101020 Servlet failed with an Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, jsf-2.2, weblogic12c

We want to migrate from WebLogic 12.1.3 to WebLogic 12.2.1.3. Our app worked fine on 12.1.3. But we are facing the java.lang.IllegalStateException after moving to each page on 12.2.1.3.

Every click to some link and visiting any page result to IllegalStateException in the console, though application seems to work fine, but some pages doesn't function.

Here is our weblogic.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd
            http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
            http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.9/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<wls:weblogic-version>12.2.1.3</wls:weblogic-version>
<wls:context-root>savet-jsf</wls:context-root>
```

faces-config.xml header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
 <managed-bean>
...
```

And web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>SAVE_T_JSF</display-name>
    <description>SAVE T JSF</description>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>picloader</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.tsystems.savet.helper.PicLoader</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>picloader</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pic/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/Redirect.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.IllegalStateException</exception-type>
    <location>/Redirect.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/Willkommen.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>cicd</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>aristo</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Erweiterte Development Tools für Facelets - Fehlermeldungen und Konsorten -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Kommentare (wie dieses hier) in xhtml werden vom Faces Servlet ignoriert. -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Wird für ECSS (extended CSS) gebraucht -->
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ecss</extension>
    <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>xhtml</extension>
    <mime-type>application/xhtml+xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<!-- Richfaces issue. RF-11103 -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- SAVE-T Taglib (Diagramme u Co.) -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/savet-taglib.xml; /WEB-INF/functions.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Listener, damit die statischen Enum Konstanten in SAVE-T richtig initialisiert 
    werden -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.tsystems.helper.listener.SaveTServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.tsystems.savet.common.session.SaveTSessionHolder</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Extended Skinning level <context-param> <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING_LEVEL</param-name> 
    <param-value>extended</param-value> </context-param> <context-param> <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNINGL</param-name> 
    <param-value>enable</param-value> </context-param> <context-param> <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING_CLASSES</param-name> 
    <param-value>enable</param-value> </context-param> -->
```

The exception looks like

```
дек 27, 2018 6:47:21 PM org.primefaces.config.WebXmlParser toDocument
WARNING: DocumentBuilderFactory#setFeature not implemented. Skipping...
<дек 27, 2018 6:47:21,843 PM MSK> <Warning> 
<org.primefaces.config.WebXmlParser> <BEA-000000> 
<DocumentBuilderFactory#setFeature not implemented. Skipping...> 
<дек 27, 2018 6:47:22,148 PM MSK> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020> 
<[ServletContext@2037446797[app:SAVE-T module:savet-jsf path:null spec-version:3.1]] Servlet failed with an Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.assertNotReleased(FacesContextImpl.java:712)
at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.getAttributes(FacesContextImpl.java:239)
at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContext.setInstance(ExtendedPartialViewContext.java:55)
at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContext.release(ExtendedPartialViewContext.java:64)
at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.release(ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.java:424)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

And it could arise once or several times when entering every page.
I've tried to change versions of web-app in headers to 3.1, I've installed primefaces and javax.faces libraries in the WebLogic console. But it doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in Oracle metalink Doc ID 2168454.1? It mentions this to be a known error solved by bundling (and overwriting WebLogic) JSF classes from a recent version from http://richfaces.jboss.org/download/stable.

Comment: I cannot sign in to oracle support, they demand some support identifier which I don't have.

Comment: To quote the (only) juicy bit from that article: 

"Download the RichFaces 4.5.x version at http://richfaces.jboss.org/download/stable, bundle it with the application (can be specified in weblogic-application.xml or weblogic.xml), and use filtering classloader to ensure the correct version is used.

Refer the topic "Using a Filtering ClassLoader" from link - https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLPRG/classloading.htm#WLPRG313"